# How to add a linked list to itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

Considering that this is my function:

```
void addtoSameList(const List &another){
   for (Node *temp = new Node(*head); temp != nullptr; temp = temp -> next){
      Node *ptr = other.head;
      Node *temp2 = new Node;
      temp2->value = temp->value;
      while (ptr -> next != nullptr) {
         ptr = ptr -> next;
      }
      ptr->next = temp2;
      temp2->next = nullptr;
   }
   return;
}
```

where my goal is to append a linkedlist to itself, I do not know exactly what goes wrong.
If, for example, I have a linkedlist called n in the main function, where I then declare:

```
n.addtoSameList(n);
```

meaning that &other is going to be pointing at the same node as n, I figured that I would make a new node and deep copy the contents of n.

However, my two outputs are either that I end up in an infinite loop, or that some node ends up getting skipped.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This looks like it has a perfectly fine minimal reproducible example implied by the text, and requests for one just look like an excuse to close a question.

Comment: First, reformat your code. Proper indenting will help you a great deal when trying to understand your own code.

Comment: @Omnifarious a [mcve] can be copied and reproduces the problem without changes. If the problem is a unexpected runtime behavior it hast to contain a `main` function.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - Yes. That is the official definition. Personally, I think it's currently being used as a bludgeon to punish someone who didn't ask an advanced enough question. It's clear what the problem is regardless of whether or not they've done that. And they aren't doing the annoying thing where they're asking for help with a problem that isn't showing in their code because they've assumed where the problem is and won't show the actual problem.

Comment: @Omnifarious The problem is that often the error is not in the shown code snippet but somewhere else.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - I know. I've experienced that once or twice myself in answering questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has numerous issues. First, the interface doesn't suggest that the only use is to append a linked list to itself. Nor does it suggest that a deep copy is necessary in any other case.

So, lets adjust the requirements...

You want a member function that will append a copy of a linked list to the existing one. Then the case of self-appending naturally falls out of the problem description.

The approach here would be to step through the linked list that is passed in, carefully copying each node, then re-adjusting the pointers on the main linked list to point at your new node and the pointer in the new node to be set to appear to be the end of the list. This maintains a list invariant as the list is stepped through.

There is a pitfall here though. If you are self appending, you risk creating an infinite loop. So you should find the end node of the passed in list before you start this process and consistently use it to find out if you've gotten to the end of the list. If you maintain a tail pointer, this is trivial. If you don't, it means a list traversal.

Another way would be to simply create a copy first, carefully maintaining the pointer to the first node of the copy. Then just adjust the tail node's next pointer to point at the new list, and then adjust the tail node (if you maintain that pointer in the LinkedList data structure) to point at the tail node of the copy. And that's probably the way you should go. It's cleaner and more efficient. The main drawback is cleanup when doing exception handling. But, at your level, you shouldn't be concerned with that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach. Create three pointers: `ptrBegin`, `ptrEnd` and `ptrNew`. `ptrBegin` points to the beginning of the linked list and traverse the linked list so that `ptrEnd` and `ptrNew` point to the last element of the linked list. Then increment `ptrBegin` until `ptrBegin != ptrEnd` at the same time copying the data at `ptrBegin` to a new node at `ptrNew->next` and increment `ptrNew`.